# Is it possible to mimic the older UICollectionView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift3, swiftui

I have been able to create the following by using the new ScrollView with Lazy Grids in iOS 14

```
ScrollView() {
    
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5) {
        
        ForEach(player, id: \.self) { play in
    
            HStack {
        
                Text("Player \(play)")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                        
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                
                    LazyHGrid(rows: rows, alignment: .center) {
                   
                        AllPicks()
            
                    }
                
                }

            }

        }
                
    }
            
}

struct AllPicks: View {

    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
        
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
        
            Text("\(item)")
                .font(.caption)
                
            Image("apr")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            
            Text("Bears")
                .font(.caption)
            
        }
    
    }

}
```

[image]

As you can see the "header" of the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... is required to be repeated for each player; as well as every Players pick is individually scrollable, which is not a desired effect.

Was hoping more like the following:

[image]

Where the X and Y (Times and channels) axises are "Sticky" and they will move as you scroll vertically or horizontal.

Has anyone been able to leverage the multi directional collection view in SwiftUI?

Comment: [Edit] your question to show your code.  You need to restructure your views.  You need something like a `HStack` where the first column is your "player" column and then the second column is a scrollview containing more HStacks.  The first row in this scrollview would be your numbers and the second and subsequent rows would be the teams or whatever they are.

Comment: @Paulw11 code has been added

Comment: @Paulw11 just wanted to follow-up on if you have any insights based on the code i provided and how i can restructure it based on your previous comment?